# Which database am I using in TYPO3?

Tags: mysql, sql, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-9.x

I have created a lot of different instances of TYPO3 versions and have not cleverly named my databases. Is there a way to find out which databse I am using with my current project (TYPO3 v9.5.12)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're an Admin/System Maintainer, you can open the TYPO3 backend module "Environment". The first module card "Environment Overview" will give you the name of the currently used database, among some other information.

As an alternative, you can open `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`, where the current database is configured. There you could also change the database, if needed.

Comment: note that information in `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` could be overwritten in `/typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`. Also database names.